# Get Array containing all data type posible values?

Tags: purescript

Isn't it possible given

```
data Letter = A | B | C | ... | Z
```

automagically get an array that contains all the possible values:

`[A, B, C, ..., Z]`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the autoderived `Generic` type class:

```hs
data Letter = ...
derive instance Generic Letter _
```

Note the underscore at the end of the `derive` line: the `Generic` type class takes two types - (1) the data type you're describing and (2) its generic description, but the latter will be provided by the compiler automatically for you. That's what the underscore means.

And then you can enumerate all elements by their indexes, using [`genericBottom`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Bounded.Generic#v:genericBottom)/[`genericTop`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Bounded.Generic#v:genericTop) to get the index range and [`genericFromEnum`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-enums/5.0.0/docs/Data.Enum.Generic#v:genericFromEnum)/[`genericToEnum`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-enums/5.0.0/docs/Data.Enum.Generic#v:genericToEnum) to convert to/from integers.

One hiccup is that `genericToEnum` returns a `Maybe`, because strictly speaking not every integer number can be converted to an enum value, but in this case you know all the numbers are valid, because you obtained them by `genericFromEnum` in the first place, so you can just `mapMaybe` instead of regular map:

```hs
allElements ::
  forall a rep.
  Generic a rep =>
  GenericBoundedEnum rep =>
  GenericTop rep =>
  GenericBottom rep =>
  Array a
allElements = mapMaybe genericToEnum (idxFrom..idxTo)
  where
    idxFrom = genericFromEnum (genericBottom :: a)
    idxTo = genericFromEnum (genericTop :: a)
```

Usage:

```hs
allLetters :: Array Letter
allLetters = allElements
```

Note that the `allElements` function is generic enough to work with any type, provided (1) all its constructors are parameterless and (2) it has a `Generic` instance.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it should be doable via Generics but didn't know how.